# pandas json normalize with some empty record_path

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to normalize a nested json but am struggling with is how to deal with NAN and empty fields as i am getting a =>  **KeyError: 'address'** when i am trying to normalize with

`pd.json_normalize(data ,record_path=["address"],record_prefix='add.')`

The data that i am using

```
data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "test",
    "last": "last"

}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "test1",
    "last": "last1",
    "address": []
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "test2",
    "last": "last2",
    "address": [{
        "steet": "streed2",
        "no": 2
    }]
}]
```

the ouptput i want

```
 id | name  | last | add.street | add.no
 1  | test  | last | NAN        | NAN
 2  | test1 | last1 |           |  
 3  | test2 | last2 | street2   | 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following approach (I took the liberty to spell-check the json-string you provided):

So, you data is:

```
data = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "test",
    "last": "last"

}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "test1",
    "last": "last1",
    "address": []
},
{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "test2",
    "last": "last2",
    "address": [{
        "street": "street d2",
        "no": 2
    }]
}]
```

and the first step is to insert it in a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

which returns:

```
 id   name   last                          address
0  1   test   last                              NaN
1  2  test1  last1                               []
2  3  test2  last2  [{'steet': 'streed2', 'no': 2}]
```

As you point out, the existence of `nan` is quite problematic. So, it is reasonable to make them "go away". First. explode the address column. That will expose the json strings and not lists of json strings:

```
df = df.explode('address')
print(df)
```

Which gives:

```
id   name   last                        address
0  1   test   last                            NaN
1  2  test1  last1                            NaN
2  3  test2  last2  {'steet': 'streed2', 'no': 2}
```

Then `nan` can be handled by replacing them with `{}` and this allows you to normalize you df.

```
df.address = df.address.fillna({i: {} for i in df.index})

# use json_normalize
df = df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.address)).drop(columns=['address'])
print(df)
```

which gives you:

```
  id   name   last     street   no
0  1   test   last        NaN  NaN
1  2  test1  last1        NaN  NaN
2  3  test2  last2  street d2  2.0
```